# MongoDB how to migrate chunk if the chunk only has one document in it and is larger than the max chunk size

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, sharding

I have recently started working for a company that has a large mongoDB instance. The document key that was chosen has some issues, specifically it is possible for a single document to continue to grow in size forever. After millions of changes a single document can be as large as 130MB+.

We are using MongoDB 2.2.1. What I am trying to do is to fix balancing because the balancer is in a loop trying to migrate some large chunks. It fails because the chunk size is larger than the default max allowed chunk size (64MB). The chunk can also not be split because it contains a single document.

The real fix is to change the document key (create a new DB instance and migrate to it), but this will take quite a  while to do and I want to put in a short term fix to help balancing. The only thing that I can think of is to increase the default chunk size from 64MB to something like 160MB so that some of our huge chunks can migrate.

My question is, is it better to:

1. Increase max chunk size to 160MB, manually move the chunk, and then decrease the max chunk size. (The large document ID's would go back to being un-migrateable at that point).
2. Permanently increase the max chunk size to 160MB and leave it there until we can migrate to a new key. (It is my understanding that increasing the chunk size can have some very drastic IO impact)
3. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single document can never be more than 16MB, but a set of documents that share the same shard key can of course together be more than 16MB.

I don't understand why you want to move that large chunk though, it should be perfectly fine on the shard it currently is at. For now, I would suggest scenario 1, as it has the least amount of impact, but you really should of course fix the shard key so that you don't have documents that share the same key be larger than 64MB.

Comment: I am completely happy to leave it where it is... mongos balancing wants to move it. :)

Is there a way to tell balancer to skip specific shard keys?

Comment: No, I don't think there is, but it surprises me that it doesn't just move other chunks instead.